# How do I get smallcaps font with the noto package?

Tags: fonts

One of my customers has requested that I switch a template I use to the `noto` font to match some of their other material. I changed

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

to

```
\usepackage{noto}
```

but `\textsc{}` does not produce the expected output:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
Example \textsc{Here}
\end{document}
```

produces the expected result:[image: Working Example]

MNWE (minimal not-working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{noto}
\begin{document}
Example \textsc{Here}
\end{document}
```

generates the warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/NotoSerif-TLF/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/NotoSerif-TLF/m/n' instead on input line 4.
```

and looks wrong: [image: Minimal Non-Working Example]

I think I understand what the warning is telling me (there's a "sc" style in the NotoSerif-TLF font that doesn't exist), but I don't understand how to fix it, or if it's a bug in the `noto` package's font files themselves. How can I use the `noto` fonts for my project and retain the `\textsc` functionality?

Comment: Important update! The new version of the `noto` package supports several new font shapes, including small caps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Noto fonts provided by TeX Live are an old version.

I downloaded the whole family from https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-fonts and the big set has small caps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}

Example \textsc{Here}

\end{document}
```

However you need XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for using the full version. No packaged version for `pdflatex` is available supporting small caps.

[image]

## UPDATE

The version of `noto.sty` released 2018-02-19 has extended support for the most recent Noto fonts. After an update, small caps work also with `pdflatex`.

Comment: fontspec worked well enough for my needs; thanks! I also emailed the package maintainer to politely request an update to get a more cross-environment solution as well, since some people who will be building these documents aren't guaranteed to have the latest noto fonts installed.

Comment: Well, I was wrong. Your example gives me:

    LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/sc' undefined
    (Font)              using `TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n' instead on input line 6.

Comment: @Jon Did you install the new fonts as system fonts?

Comment: Yep - the smcp style in the noto fonts is in their repository, but not in their downloadable package. If you want to use egreg's solution, make sure you use the git repo!

Comment: @Jon I hate to quote myself, but I think the first paragraph was clear enough, pointing to the Git repository.

Comment: Well, I installed the github font that I verified has the smallcaps glyphs, and I'm still getting the same warning about replacing TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/sc with TU/NotoSerif(0)/m/n. I can't reproduce the success from yesterday!

Comment: Figured it out - miktex on this machine was using its own installation of noto rather than the system's fonts: %appdata%\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\truetype\google\noto

Comment: @Jon Check carefully that you don’t have multiple instances of Noto Serif in your system. A good method is calling `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -v" <file>` and checking the console output.